# Java GUI Toolbar

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, awt

I am developing a Java Desktop Application. In that I want some toolbars at the top of the JFrame (as in usual GUI appllications).

I want to allow user to add/remove toolbars dynamically by clicking on some buttons. How can I implement this (through any Layouts or some other way) so that when a user add/removes a toolbar, the rest of the space below the toolbar is adjusted accordingly.

Comment: This is an almost exact duplicate of another question of yours I answered about half an hour ago: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012011/problem-in-java-gui>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you using BorderLayout for the program and keep the North area for the toolbars. To this (North) area add another container (with BoxLayout or FlowLayout), depending on how you want your toolbars to be added/where placed in the container.

Have a look at [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) Java Layout Manager tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the correct LayoutManager and add/remove the components, the layout should be computed automatically.

```
  JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  p.add(someComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Now if you later execute something like

```
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      p.add(newComponent, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
  });
```

I think (but haven't tested) that the panel will automatically relayout itself to match the new configuration.

Comment: If you're responding to button clicks, you don't even have to go through the hassle of using `invokeLater` since you're already on the EDT.

Comment: For a toolbar I would use BorderLayout.PAGE_START instead of NORTH

Answer (score 0):

I got my toolbar to finally work by making a JPanel for all the toolbars (setting the "box" layout for that JPanel), putting my JToolBar toolbars on the JPanel, and putting my buttons on their respective JToolBar to group them. I'm using NetBeans, which generates the code, so I can't effectively put the code here.

With that setup, I can use the setVisible() method to show and hide individual buttons and JToolBar's. The documentation states that the validate() method should be used to reposition the buttons, but it works for me without it, at least under Windows 7. When I tried it under Ubuntu 10, the layout of the toolbar was wrong, so my answer is partially correct for now.